# How to run jupyter notebook on AWS EC2 with Ubuntu, Nginx, and Gunicorn

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, nginx, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

My system is an AWS EC2 running Ubuntu 20.04 for an existing site https://www.takir.org using the Django web framework. It's using Nginx webserver and gunicorn. I can't get jupyter notebook to run in the browser at [https://www.takir.org/notebook/](https://www.takir.org:8888/notebook/).

I already had the security group for the existing site but added port 8888.

[image: picture of my security group settings]

I installed Anaconda and ran `conda info`.

I ran `jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8888`. The output provided a link `http://localhost:8888/?token=<token>` which worked in my browser. I could see Jupyter and the file directory for the files on the ec2.

I created a password using `jupyter notebook password` and got the hashed password from the output .json file. Then I ran

```
cd ~
mkdir ssl
cd ssl
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout mykey.key -out mycert.pem
```

Then I ran `jupyter notebook --certfile=~/ssl/mycert.pem --keyfile ~/ssl/mykey.key`.

I ran `jupyter notebook --generate-config` and set the following parameters:

```
c = get_config()
c.NotebookApp.ip = '0.0.0.0'
c.NotebookApp.password = u'<PASSWORD HASH>'
c.NotebookApp.port = 8888
c.NotebookApp.certfile = u'/home/ubuntu/ssl/mycert.pem'
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False
```

I also added edited the nginx settings at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/<myproject>`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 18.189.52.54;
    ...

    # start of addition for jupyter
    location /notebook {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_read_timeout 86400;
    } # end of addition for jupyter

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }

}
...
```

When I run `jupyter notebook`, pointing the browser to http://18.189.52.54/notebook/ gives me the nginx Bad Gateway error. http://18.189.52.54:8888/ gives me a "can't reach this page" error.

The terminal errors are the following:
[image]
and
[image]

When I commented out the .certfile line in jupyter notebook configuration file and run `jupyter notebook`, I get a `404 GET /notebook (127.0.0.1) 25.590000ms referer=None` error in the terminal. I also tried deleting the cert folder and recreating it. It still didn't work.

I recognize that I may need to add the location block to the server block for the domain name in the nginx configuration file but wanted to see if it could work here before adding another layer of complications.

I also added `c.ServerApp.trust_xheaders = True` but that didn't work.

Update:
Drawing from @Paolo's comment below, I added `c.ServerApp.allow_remote_access=True` to my jupyter configuration file. I also commented out the .certfile line. I now can use the `jupyter nbclassic --no-browser` to run jupyter notebook in the terminal, use the output link in the browser and enter my password for jupyter notebook, and create and save a new notebook.

The part that is still broken is having nginx serve the page. It still doesn't work using the HTTP://public_IP_address/notebook. Specifically, http://18.189.52.54/notebook produces the 404 Page Not Found error. But when I added a /tree and /login location block like the /notebook block in the nginx configurations file, the jupyter notebook comes through but the static files are not being served. It appears the issue is how to get jupyter to serve all the pages without interfering with the existing website.

Please assist.

Comment: Normally you would expose is through ssh tunnel. This is the most common and most secure way.

Comment: @Marcin, I don't understand what you are explaining to do to fix the problem. If you mean open a new terminal and use `ssh -i ~/mykeypair.pem -N -f -L 8888:localhost:8888 ubuntu@ec2-###-##-##-###.compute-1.amazonaws.com`, this gives me the error `Name or service not known` even though it is almost a copy and paste of the regular ssh command that I have demonstrated that I am already using to do what I have posted in the question details. Even if I could do this, you did not provide enough details to follow with no browser.

Comment: I've created a reference architecture that stands up a jupyter notebook behind nginx. You can check it out here https://github.com/paololazzari/jupyter-on-ec2

Comment: Thanks, @Paolo. Drawing from the jupyter notebook section of your .yml file, I added `c.ServerApp.allow_remote_access=True` to my jupyter configuration file. I now can use the `jupyter notebook --no-browser` and `jupyter nbclassic --no-browser`   to run jupyter notebook, go to the browser and enter my password for jupyter notebook, and create a new notebook. I will come back after looking more at your .yml nginx section.